# A file in a loop cannot be read more than 17 times

Tags: c++, malloc

I have a program that reads a set of input files (each around 130MB) and perform some data searching. The program have to read all input files several times. The reading is performed by a loop. Everything works fine until the loop reaches the 17th iteration. Then the following message appears (vvfield is the name of the main program):

```
vvfield(13053) malloc: *** error for object 0x100100301: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap
```

The loop can be performed with less than 17 times, and works perfect, however if the loop is performed more than 17 times, then the message appears. The main concern is that the program is supposed to perform the loop more than 200 times

I don't know if there is a limit to the number of times a file can be read.

The input files are open, closed and cleared in an independent function, and each input file is read from the beginning to some point (the point is variable, but can be the end of file sometimes).

I am using g++ for compiling, and working on Mac OS Snow Leopard 10.6.7

Anyone has an idea about what could be happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if (mindReadingMode.IsSwitchOn()) std::cout << "you are leaking memory!" << std::cout;

Comment: You know that c++ has no intrinsic garbage collector and you have to free memory by yourself? (Btw. use new/delete instead of malloc/free)

Comment: There are no such limitations in C or C++. You need to show us your file reading code.

Comment: Vote to close, too localized. Future visitors will not be helped by this question.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, here's what it's telling you: after 17 times around the loop, you are trying to free a pointer that no longer points to a malloc'd block.  Why?  Since it happens 17 times, I'd suspect you have the pointers in an array and you have messed up some index, or overflowed an array.  Look at anyplace you may have allocated 16 of anything.

Without the code it's very hard to help more; however, I assume it's crashing at that point, so you can use *gdb* to find out exactly where.

Now, here's the $64K question: if you're writing C++, why are you using `malloc` and free?  What about `new` and `delete`?

Comment: Actually this is very rare, because I do use new and delete[]. The array that apparently is suffering some damage is an array of strings, (containing the names of the input files), however this array is only allocated once, at the beginning of the program. The problem with the code is that is large and split in several files. I will try to use gdb. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I really thank all your help! :D Finally, I have solved the problem. But I would like to say how I solved it.

It turns out that all allocation (with new function) and deallocation (with delete[] function) of arrays had no errors per se, but a kind of "naive" mistake.

Apparently the g++ compiler does not work properly if you do not perform an inquiry about the state of the pointer. For example, the function that I changed is the following:

```
void clearSingleBinVars(real** &mean,real** &sd,int** &npart)
{
   extern int maxNoFrames;
   for (int i=0; i<maxNoFrames; i++) {
      delete[] mean[i];
      delete[] sd[i];
      delete[] npart[i];
   }
   delete[] mean; mean=NULL;
   delete[] sd; sd=NULL;
   delete[] npart; npart=NULL;
}
```

I add some code and the new function is:

```
void clearSingleBinVars(real** &mean,real** &sd,int** &npart)
{
   extern int maxNoFrames;
   /*Added code: next four lines*/
   if ((mean==NULL)||(sd==NULL)||(npart==NULL)) {
      cout << "Warning: attempting to deallocate null arrays!\n";
      return;
   }
   for (int i=0; i<maxNoFrames; i++) {
      delete[] mean[i]; mean[i]=NULL;//added mean[i]=NULL;
      delete[] sd[i]; sd[i]=NULL;//added sd[i]=NULL;
      delete[] npart[i]; npart[i]=NULL;//added npart[i]=NULL;
   }
   delete[] mean; mean=NULL;
   delete[] sd; sd=NULL;
   delete[] npart; npart=NULL;
}
```

With this changes, everything works fine!

What is really impressive is that I do not get any warning message, i.e. When the program is running there are not mistaken allocations/deallocations... I just add the warning message and solved the problem.

My opinion is that it is a compiler stuff. So the advise is whenever you repeatedly allocate/deallocate an object ALWAYS check the pointer and ALWAYS set it to NULL when deallocate, even if you are sure that no bad allocations/deallocations ocurr!

Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps you, but there is limitation in the size of files that you can read in C++ and that is 2GB. Maybe this is the source of your problem: 130*16 = 2080 MB. I am not sure about this, but it is worth a check.

Comment: Thanks! I do not think this is the problem, that is the reason I open and close the input files each time in the loop. Actually I am using 10 input files, each around 130M, even with these ten files, occurs the same, the program crashes at the 17th iteration. By that time, the program has read (130*10*17)M. The allocated memory does not grow. Anyway, I appreciate your help =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to post some code because there are some important ambiguities that need to be resolved:

- File Reading
- Data Allocation
- Memory Management

These different issues may be the cause of failure for your program.

### File Reading

File reading has two aspects:  the file variable (or handle to the file), a.k.a. `std::fstream`, and the destination of the data.  The file or stream variable *does not need to be allocated in dynamic memory*, and neither does the buffer, or data variables.  When reading a file more than once, a good process is to not allocate the buffer or stream for each iteration.  A file can be repositioned without closing or deleting of the file variable.

### Data Allocation

Your error stems from dynamic memory allocation.  Prefer to use local define variable, or static variables to dynamically allocated variables.  Unlike `Java` or `C#`, C++ allows variables to be declared in local (stack) storage area or in an automatic area (such as static variables in functions or global variables).  Reducing the quantity of dynamically allocated variables reduces the possibility of memory leaks, memory fragmentation or running out of memory.

Also, if you can, allocate the variables once (before reading the file).  There is an overhead to creating (allocating) variables.  When creating variables inside loops, the overhead becomes noticeable.  For large quantities of iterations (above 5 or 10) consider re-using variables that are allocated outside of the loop.

### Memory Management

Performing a few memory allocations is not bad for a program.  However, in the case of many iterations, memory allocation can be a nightmare.  Worst case, when a dynamically allocated variable is deleted (freed, returned to the memory pool), the memory it occupied will not be used again.  Most compilers and operating systems have reduced this possibility, by devising methods for combining memory fragments when possible.  However, there is a possibility that fragments cannot be combined and thus your program will run out of {usable} memory.  For example, if your program needs 64 contiguous bytes, but there are only 64 bytes scattered around, the allocation will fail.

Also, other languages support Garbage Collection.  This is the concept of coagulating memory fragments.  The C++ language does not come with Garbage Collection.  If you want the service, you will have to create your own memory pool (`placement new`) and write your own G.C.

### Summary

We need more information from you, such as the code fragment where the error occurs and the exact (verbatim) message from the compiler or operating system.  Your original post does not contain enough information to resolve some ambiguities listed above.